# Incrementing a variable by 0.025 for each loop in BASH (NOT loop variable)

Tags: bash

I wanted to increment a variable, k inside a loop. Each increment is by 0.025. I tried using:

`let "k += 0.025"`

and

`let "$k += 0.025"`

and

`k += 0.025`

and many other variations. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use integer math and then convert to decimal when needed.

```
#!/bin/bash

k=25

# Start of loop
#

  # Increment variable by 0.025 (times 1000).
  #
  let k="$k+25"

  # Get value as fraction (uses bc).
  #
  v=$(echo "$k/1000"|bc -l)

# End of loop
#    
echo $v
```

Save as `t.sh`, then:

```
$ chmod +x t.sh
$ ./t.sh 
.05000000000000000000
```

Comment: @Amit: Don't know what to tell you, Amit; the code works as shown. DigitalRoss makes a good point: This is more suitable for `awk`; to write it in `bash` is hand-cuffing yourself.

Answer (score 9):

You may be working on some giant bash masterpiece that can't be rewritten without a king's ransom.

Alternatively, this problem may be telling you "*write me in **Ruby** or **Python** or **Perl** or **Awk***".

Comment: I am upvoting this even though I have, indeed, written giant bash masterpieces that took a king's ransom to rewrite (jn Java for some reason)

Comment: I'm stuck scripting on an embedded system, but this (my tenth visit to SO) has me tempted to write my script in python and have it telnet to the embedded system to execute the few commands that need to be executed on the embedded system, allowing everything else to happen on another machine with python.

Answer (score 7):

```
#!/bin/sh

k=1.00
incl=0.025
k=`echo $k + $incl | bc`

echo $k
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash doesn't handle floating point math whatsoever. You need help from an external tool like [bc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_programming_language).

Comment: This helps. So I would do something like: `bc -l k += 0.025` and leave the rest the same?

Comment: Well, tsu1980's answer is a more concrete example.